# SSIS import access text to SQL Server in varchar (not nvarchar) format

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssis

Currently I want to manually import all tables (60+) in an access (2016) accdb file to SQL Server. Then I will truncate all those tables and build a SSIS job to load them to SQL Server (truncate table and full load) daily.

I created a new database in SQL Server. When I manually import all tables from access to the new database in SQL Server, I notice all text columns in those tables turn to be `nvarchar`. Actually I need them to be `varchar`.

Do I have to change table structure for all those columns in SQL Server or it there any easy way when I import data, I can convert it to `varchar`?

Comment: Text and Memo columns have stored Unicode characters since Access 2000 (albeit with a janky compression scheme). How are you importing the data into SQL Server? If your Access DB only stores US-ASCII characters then you should be able to easily map the incoming columns into varchar columns in SQL Server.

Comment: I tried to import data from access as it is. It is US-ASCII characters but I do find Text and Memo columns. So I have to import at nVarchar then convert to Varchar?